# Is it possible to compile the Debian Alien package for termux, and if so how?

Tags: debian

I know that Debian and termux packages are not compatible but I think it can be done, compile the Debian Alien package for termux, which processes a package of any format and returns an installable program for termux.

It would be great, it would open up a horizon of possibilities.

I had this crazy idea, many people creating programs for termux but there are a lot of packages already created, it would only be to take the executable, pass it to the program and return an installable package for termux.

Many of us do not have a PC and we see in termux the possibility of being able to enjoy and learn from this great operating system that is GNU-Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `alien` software only converts a supplied package to one of the supported package types.  I do not believe it changes any paths or does anything to ensure compatibility with `termux`.  Since both Debian and `termux` use `.deb` packages, I do not know how `alien` could help in what you are trying to do.

There are notes from the [`termux` wiki](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux) about using a different `libc` then most Linux distributions (Bionic libc vs glibc) preventing most prebuilt binaries from working within `termux` at all.

I found that [`termux` maintains a number of official package repositories and there also seems to be community supported package repositories](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management), have you checked all of these to see if they offer the software you want?

If the software you want is not currently offered anywhere as `termux` packages, I believe a remaining option would be to build your own packages from source or [request someone make the package for you](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues).